# iOS xcode Map zoom in

Tags: xcode

I have the  map currently working when the user click on the buttons.

How can I zoom into the map  and possibly animate as it xooms in, when the user click on the buttons.

Here are hte main files and the header files. Also, how can i show my  current location?

Thanks in advance
main file

```
@synthesize map;


//Add Map overlay

-(MKOverlayView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay{



    MKCircleView* circleView =[[MKCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];

    circleView.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    circleView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return circleView;



}


-(IBAction)onLocationButtonTop:(id)sender {





    UIBarButtonItem* b = (UIBarButtonItem*) sender;

    int tag = b.tag;



    float latitude = 40.0;

    float longitude  = -75.0;



    if(tag == 1){

        latitude = 57.15;longitude  = -2.15;

    }

    else if(tag == 2){

        latitude = 39.91;longitude  = 116.41;

    }

    else{

        latitude = -1.46;longitude  = -48.48;

    }



    CLLocationCoordinate2D x;

    x.latitude = latitude;

    x.longitude = longitude;









    MKCoordinateSpan z;

    z.latitudeDelta = 0.25;

    z.longitudeDelta = 0.25;



    MKCoordinateRegion y;

    y.center = x;

    y.span = z;



    map.region = y;

    [map addOverlay:[MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:x

                                                 radius:1000]];



}
```

h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@interface MapExampleK2ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>



@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView* map;


-(IBAction)onLocationButtonTop:(id)sender;



@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For second part of your question You can use CLLocationManager to get you current location and then use setRegion when the location updates. You can refer to region code posted on http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Regions/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010726.

Below is the function from that code that is setting focus on the map to your current location.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation %@ from %@", newLocation, oldLocation);
    
        if (oldLocation == nil) {
        // Zoom to the current user location.
        MKCoordinateRegion userLocation = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate, 1500.0, 1500.0);
        [regionsMapView setRegion:userLocation animated:YES];
    }
}
```